# Set up a Postfix server on Ubuntu for use with Apple Mail (or any mail client)

Tags: postfix, smtp, email

I set up a Postfix server on my Ubuntu VPS and it works for sending email from the `mail` utility in the command line. I set up SPF records, DKIM, pretty much everything I could read about. However, I'd like to be able to send and receive email without SSHing into my box each time.

When I try to set up my server (borogov.es) with my mail client, and I use "mail.borogov.es" as my outgoing mail server, I get "Server not responding." I feel like this is an access issue of some sort, but I'm not sure.

I'm not running a firewall. What could be going on?

Answer (score 1):

See what `netstat -tlnp` returns; if Postfix is listening to `127.0.0.1:25`, then it's bound to loopback interface instead of a network card interface.

In that case your Postfix `/etc/postfix/main.cf` does not have `inet_interfaces = all` line.

The other option is that your ISP does not allow private SMTP servers.

Comment: It is listening on `all`, and DigitalOcean does allow SMTP servers.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be attempting to send mail from your email client on port 25; rather using 587 (the standard submission port). Port 25 is meant for transfer *between* mail servers, and many home ISPs block it to reduce spam from compromised home computers.

Your Postfix server isn't listening on port 587:

```
$ telnet mail.borogov.es 587
Trying 198.199.97.52...
telnet: connect to address 198.199.97.52: Connection refused
```

This means you probably forgot to set up a `submission` section in Postfix's `master.cf` configuration file. It should look something like:

```
submission inet n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
```

Comment: I just paste that into my master.cf?

Comment: So I get this: http://i.imgur.com/suBgWrt.png

Comment: After restarting Postfix, that is.